# Bootstrap always show submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

On my mobile part of the site I want to show the submenu without having to click/hover the parent.

HTML:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown "><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="/">Home</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" >
            <li><a href="/home/news/">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="/home/contact/">Contact</a>
            <li><a href="/home/about-us/">About us</a></li>
        </ul>
    <li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I want to show the submenu without having to click or hover the parent. Codes I'm using is CSS, Javascript and Jquery so I can use one (or all) of them to make this. Using the latest version of Bootstrap to make the site (3.3.6).

EDIT
The JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uvd5jp0o/

Here you can also see I've made the submenu display on hover in jquery.

Comment: can you add your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: You can use `pull-left` class `<li class="dropdown-submenu pull-left">`

Comment: Included the jsfiddle :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the class **visible-xs-** to make the nav displayed in mobile browsers

Checkout the bootstrap website

http://getbootstrap.com/css/

> So, for extra small (xs) screens for example, the available
>   .visible-*-* classes are: .visible-xs-block, .visible-xs-inline, and
>   .visible-xs-inline-block.

Comment: Its great option for visible only in extra-small screen.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can set a width when you whant the menu to show, like this:

```
window.onload = checkWindowSize;
window.onresize = checkWindowSize;

function checkWindowSize() {
  if ($(window).width() < "768") { //example width of 768px
    $("#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 li").addClass('open');
  }else{
    $("#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 li").removeClass('open');
  }
}
```

Or you can use the built in class in bootstrap and add it to your ul-element like this:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu visible-xs">
```

The codes will check the window width and only react when the width is smaller then 768px

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

## [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/FGv50sv4l4)

Use some piece of script :)

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul id="Drp" class="dropdown-menu visible-xs">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

SCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 CheckScreenSize();
});

window.onresize = function(event) {
  CheckScreenSize();
};


function CheckScreenSize(){

 if($(window).width()<768){
  $("#Drp").addClass('visible-xs');
  }else
  {
  $("#Drp").removeClass('visible-xs');
  }
}
```